# how to update Asus K012

Tags: updates, asus-zenfone-5, asus-zenfone-2, asus-padfone-t00c, asus-fonepad-8

Help, my asus fonepad 7 (k012) won't update automatically, so I was forced to update it manually. Now I'm on UL-K012-WW-10.32.1.33.1-user when I go to asus website there is alot of update for my K012.. should I update it gradually(one update at a time starting from old to newer update) or I have just take latest update from asus website??

sorry for my english 
thank you good sir(^_^)